# Importance of the place of CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: service, docker, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile that works fine, but I was told that maybe it wasn't the best way to do what I wanted :

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lighttpd php5-cgi php5-common php5 php5-mysql php5-gd
RUN echo server.modules += \(\"mod_rewrite\"\) >> /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
CMD ["lighttpd", "-D", "-f", "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf"]
RUN lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php
RUN service lighttpd restart
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

As you can see, I am creating an image for a container with lighttpd and php.

My question is about the place of the CMD part in my Dockerfile. I was told that it was better to put it at the end of the file, but as you can see, I did it in the middle of mine and it worked just fine.

It does not stop the creation nor does it interfere with the `service lighttpd restart` in the run part below it.

Is there any best practice regarding this or is this normal? Could I create a Dockerfile with my CMD just after the apt-get install?

Thanks for your answers regarding my question and sorry for my english if there is any big mistakes.

Comment: Why include `RUN service lighttpd restart`? In the image, there isn't a single process running (those are only in containers), so having a layer that does nothing more than starts a process that wasn't running with the restart command, and then immediately exiting since `service` will quickly exit, makes little sense.

Comment: I know now, but It's only been two weeks since I started docker and this file was my first try at something that was working. I have a new version after speeking with someone, where there is no more restart and only a CMD at the end of the file but we were wondering why it worked well with these "error" of conception ^^

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's more of a logical preference, no need to define the command when the image isn't ready yet. There is an added convenience that debugging with the CMD or ENTRYPOINT set to a shell may make debugging a failed build a little easier. But otherwise, the last ENTRYPOINT and/or CMD modifies the config of the image and gets inherited to all child images (each line of your Dockerfile).

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter where you put the `CMD` entry in terms of Docker using that as the default command (plus Docker will use the last one if there is more than one). Where it might make a difference is if you were trying to structure your build in order to optimize caching the layers. I.e., you want to put anything that is likely to change lower down in the Dockerfile.

I think it's more convention to put it last and makes it easier to read. Is there a specific reason in your case you *don't* want to put it last?

Comment: Nope, It was just a bad interpretation of my part after reading a lot of Dockerfile I append to see one with the CMD at the middle of the file and I had an error at the begining where it told me that the service wasn't running when it was trying to use the lighty-enable-mod. I thought at the time that putting the CMD before doing my command would do the trick, and coincidentally it did...